# My app scrolls very bad after importing roboto font in assets/fonts folder

Tags: android, performance, fonts, scroll

My application running android ice cream sandwich, after importing roboto.ttf and roboto-bold.ttf fonts in fonts folder and after setting four textviews with these fonts, is very (VERY) slow while scrolling the listview.
Does anyone know a method to optimize performances? Are there any tips and tricks to improve the speed?

I clarify that it was very smooth before inserting these lines of code:

```
Typeface roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
    Typeface robotobold = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
    nome.setTypeface(robotobold);
    mq.setTypeface(roboto);
    citta.setTypeface(roboto);
    prezzo.setTypeface(roboto);
    descrizione.setTypeface(roboto);
```

I add the class that can help with font caching:

```
public class TypefaceCache {
  private final HashMap<String, Typeface> map;
  private Context con;
  public TypefaceCache(Context con) {
              map = new HashMap<String, Typeface>();
              this.con = con;
  }


  public Typeface getTypeface(String file) {
    Typeface result = map.get(file);
    if (result == null) {
      result = Typeface.createFromAsset(con.getAssets(), file);
      map.put(file, result);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

I call the class and the font through

```
    TypefaceCache typecache = new TypefaceCache(activity);
    Typeface roboto = typecache.getTypeface("fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
```

but the result is the same...

Comment: I create a typefaceCache object as you can view from my post, i create a typeface object and i immediatly put the font in the textview. I call that code in an asynctask that starts at the activity launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my solution:
in the asynctask in which i launch the ui i insert the class variable

```
private final HashMap<String, Typeface> map;
```

and then i initialyze it through the class constructor

```
map = new HashMap<String, Typeface>();
```

i implement the method that loads my typeface in the class:

```
private Typeface getTypeface(String file, Context context) {
    Typeface result = map.get(file);
    if (result == null) {
      result = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), file);
      map.put(file, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

then, whenever i want in the asynctask, i add my favourite typeface i loaded on my textviews and all is very smooth.
Thank you to all

Answer (score 4):

You could try caching your `Typeface`.

```
public class TypefaceCache {
  private final HashMap<String, Typeface> map =
      new HashMap<String, Typeface>();

  private Typeface getTypeface(String file, Context context) {
    Typeface result = map.get(file);
    if (result == null) {
      result = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), file);
      map.put(file, result);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited my post with your class, thank you for your answer but it isn't going better

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem not long ago,  solution was to set class to static, much like it's described in this [blog](http://www.levinotik.com/2011/09/22/custom-fonts-in-android-can-cause-issues-heres-how-to-fix-it/);

```
public class TypefaceSingleton {  
    private static TypefaceSingleton instance = new TypefaceSingleton();  
    private TypefaceSingleton() {}  

    public static TypefaceSingleton getInstance() { 
        return instance; 
    }  
    public Typeface getTypeface() { 
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(ThinkNearApp.getContext().getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you explain me better how to proceed please?